# Google Bar Chart

Tags: google-api

I'm a newbie person that try to playing with Google API. I try to draw a bar chart and my expect result are 12 of horizontal bar.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chs=750x300&chd=t:5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60&chxt=x,y&chco=CCFFCC|CCFF99&chxl=1:|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aus|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec

But google give me only 9 bars. What wrong with my parameter.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chart is too short. Try:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chs=750x400&chd=t:5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60&chxt=x,y&chco=CCFFCC|CCFF99&chxl=1:|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aus|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec

(changed height to 400px)

Comment: Is it have easy way to get weight and height of the image that close to my data?